# How to remove the first word of a string in a whole column?

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with columns of names and surnames. I need to remove all the first names, leaving only the surnames, this in the first column, that is to say, eliminating the first part of the text in every cell of the first column.

```
Sociologist             Referencia
1  Peter Abell            Peter Abell
2  Mark Abrams            Mark Abrams
3  Janet Abu-Lughod       Janet Abu-Lughod
4  Jane Addams            Jane Addams
5  Theodor W. Adorno      Theodor W. Adorno
6  Richard Alba           Richard Alba
```

I tried with a code taken from a similar question, but it eliminates the surnames, not the first names, which is what i need. The code is as follows:

```
Sociologos_df$word<- sub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", Sociologos_df$word)
```

So, how do i remove the first part of strings in a column?

Comment: That pattern doesn't take into account certain lastname-preceders, such as "De" or "Van" or similar ... but none of your examples have that, so perhaps we can avoid those. It'd be possible to build those in as exceptions, but that complicates the regex quite a bit.

Comment: @r2evans that would remove up to the last space.

Comment: yes, it will, and that's under the assumption that everything after that space is desired. Is that not correct?

Comment: You should specify what should happen for the cases `Mary Ann Summers` and `Sacha Baron Cohen`? The first example is two first names and the second is two last names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `sub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", df$word)` for your first names, then you can use the analog for last names:

```r
sub(".*\\s([A-Za-z]+)$", "\\1", dat$Sociologist)
# [1] "Abell"  "Abrams" "Lughod" "Addams" "Adorno" "Alba"
```

Notice that we're chopping `Abu-` off, though, in which case you might want to expand the logic for letters.

```r
sub(".*\\s([-A-Za-z]+)$", "\\1", dat$Sociologist)
# [1] "Abell"      "Abrams"     "Abu-Lughod" "Addams"     "Adorno"     "Alba"
```

Note that the leading `-` in `[-A-Za-z]` indicates the literal dash, where any other dashes indicate character ranges (i.e., `A-Z` indicates *"from `A` to `Z`, lexicographically).

Alternatively, if you want to be a little more liberal, then you can use `\\S` (capital "S") to indicate "any non-whitespace":

```r
sub(".*\\s(\\S+)$", "\\1", dat$Sociologist)
```

This produces the same output as the previous, but it allows for perhaps some other characters, such as a single-quote (e.g., `D'Angelo`) and perhaps others I'm not considering well here. While I suspect the "non-whitespace" logic will deal well-enough with accented letters and varying last names, names like "Van Wilder" will not be caught correctly (assuming you want "van" in there as well).

Also problems, "Jr", "Sr", "III", "IV", etc. There are many patterns that are good starts for detecting all of these (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s18.html), though often it might be better to not try to get them all in one pattern regex (e.g., look for "III", "IV", first, capture and remove, then try for last names).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Not getting too much into regex and keeping it simple we can use `word` from `stringr` to extract the last word in each name assuming that is going to be the surname.

```
stringr::word(df$Sociologist, -1)
#[1] "Abell"      "Abrams"     "Abu-Lughod" "Addams"     "Adorno"     "Alba"
```

This might not be a general solution but should work for the majority of cases.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Sociologist = c("Peter Abell", "Mark Abrams", 
"Janet Abu-Lughod", "Jane Addams", "Theodor W. Adorno", "Richard Alba"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```